# How to parse XML array in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am doing parsing, in my parsearray having only two data number of alerts and number of events these are fine. When we are finding the value like

```
NSString *alertcount = [[xmlparseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"alerts"];
```

and assigning these string value into label

```
mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", alertcount];
```

same for Events.

then it becomes crash. It says:

> index 0 beyond out of empty Array

And these parsing I am using in @RootViewController:

```
UITableViewController {


}
```

not using custom cell. In this rootviewcontroller class we are using 7 row(these are constant) and I want to assign at row number 5 the value of alert (i.e. `mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", alertcount]`) at the right position of cell number 5 same is cell number 6.

Comment: In your case, you should not set the no.of rows as 7constant and if your array count was 2 but indexpath.row goes upto 7. this will lead to get crash as empty arrays have been found.

Comment: Also, you can accept answers to attract a wider range of people to help you

Comment: Yes @prasanna these seven rows is constant and we are assign like cell.textlabel.text = @"Alert"; i am doing deviding sections means e sections and return 1st section 3 row and section section return [xmlParseArray count]; and 3rd section return 2 row but at section at 2nd ([xmlParseArray count];) generate no row.

Comment: However you are using indexpath.row to retrive the array since you had only 2elements there. you should write by your own index then.

Answer (score 1):

Your `xmlparseArray` might be empty. Check if you have any elements in the array. Pls show the code where you populate the array so that we can have a better idea of where you are going wrong

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Init"]){
 } 
 [xmlValue setString:@""];
}
    
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
 [xmlValue appendString:string];
    
}

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"alerts"]) {
        [currentItem setValue:[NSString stringWithString:xmlValue] forKey:elementName];
 }else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"events"]) {
        [currentItem setValue:[NSString stringWithString:xmlValue] forKey:elementName];
    }

Comment: else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Init"]) {
  [self.xmlParseArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:currentItem]];
 } 
 
 NSLog(@"xmlArray is : %@",xmlParseArray);

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return 7;

Comment: eventString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.xmlParseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"alerts"]];

Comment: alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.xmlParseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"events"]];

Comment: You'd better put all this stuff in the question ... this way it's impossible to understand!